# JQuery select all divs to reset background colour

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamically generated div named time_holder which has a number of occurences depending on the amount of rows returned from a database.

When one of the divs is clicked I want the background to change colour and all the other time_holder divs to remain or change back to the original colour. I though a simple reset would have done the job but this does not seem to work :

```
$(document).on('click', '.time_holder', function(){
$('.time_holder').css('background-color', '#EODEF3');
$(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
});
```

I was expecting the first line to reset all the timeholder divs to the original colour and then the second line to change the background of the clicked div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addClass` isn't for adding attributes. Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/). Here's [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/nFn43/), simplifying a bit event binding:

```
$('.time_holder').on('click', function() {
    $('.time_holder').css('background-color', 'red');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
});​
```

Comment: actually my typo - your example above is as I should have written it although the previously clicked div still remains the 'clicked' colour. I was trying to us the class switch method as an alternative. I have edited my post to reflect this :)

Comment: As the code containing the time_holder div is dynamically generated and not in the original DOM this method does not seem to work - my original code works but does not reset all the divs to the original colour.

Comment: Can you amend the fiddle in my example to show how you build the `time_holder` elements?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working using this code:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.time_holder', function(){
$('.time_holder').removeClass('link_bg').addClass('normal_bg');
$(this).addClass('link_bg');
});
```

but can't understand why the original is not happening.....